Book in which prehistoric hominids have engineered space travel machines that can fly close to light speed. A group travels to ancient Egypt
I have forgotten both the author's name and the title of this book and would love to read it again.
The hominids, who have some dinosaur-like features, are highly technically advanced. They detect a destructive warming trend in the Earth's climate and decide to cause a nuclear winter, simultaneously launching their two space craft. They agree to meet at a certain year in the future. One craft, however, shortens the trip and lands in ancient Egypt. There the hominids are hailed as gods and given the names Ra, Anubis, etc.
Has anyone read this?

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  When did you read this?  Do you remember the cover art?
